# How to update IP range values dynamically in Periodic Asset Discovery class from user input data?

Tags: c#

```
  internal sealed class PeriodicAssetDiscovery : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<PeriodicAssetDiscovery> _logger;
        private readonly ISchedulerService _schedulerService;
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

        private readonly JobKey jobKey = new JobKey("asset-discovery", "asset");

        public PeriodicAssetDiscovery(ILogger<PeriodicAssetDiscovery> logger, ISchedulerService schedulerService,
            IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, IEventHub eventHub)
        {
            this._logger = logger;
            this._schedulerService = schedulerService;
            this._scopeFactory = scopeFactory;

            //Fired when a backup configuration requires some change.
            eventHub.Subscribe<ConfigChangedEvent<Scan>>(async eventData => await ScheduleInternal(discoveryConfigChangedEventArgs: eventData).ConfigureAwait(false));
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"StartAsync() -> Starting hosted service ...");

            await ScheduleInternal(null, cancellationToken);

            _logger.LogInformation($"StartAsync() -> Hosted service started...");
        }

        private async Task ScheduleInternal(ConfigChangedEvent<Scan>? discoveryConfigChangedEventArgs = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            try
            {
                var shouldChangeSchedule = discoveryConfigChangedEventArgs switch
                {
                    null => true, // Default initialization
                    { } discovery when // scan rollover is changed
                        discovery.OldConfig.IsPeriodicDiscoveryEnabled != discovery.NewConfig.IsPeriodicDiscoveryEnabled => true,
                    { } discovery when // scan rollover is changed
                        discovery.OldConfig.DiscoverySchedule != discovery.NewConfig.DiscoverySchedule => true,
                    _ => false // For all other changes no need to change the scheduler.
                };

                if (!shouldChangeSchedule)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("ScheduleInternal() -> No need to change the scheduler configuration. New discovery config enabled status:[{@IsPeriodicDiscoveryEnabled}], Discovery Frequency:[{@DiscoverySchedule}]",
                        discoveryConfigChangedEventArgs?.NewConfig.IsPeriodicDiscoveryEnabled, discoveryConfigChangedEventArgs?.NewConfig.DiscoverySchedule);
                    return;
                }

                var existingJobDetail = await _schedulerService.Scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobKey, cancellationToken);

                if (existingJobDetail != null)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($" The job [{jobKey.Name}] already running. stopping");
                    await _schedulerService.Scheduler.DeleteJob(jobKey, cancellationToken);
                }

                using var serviceScope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
                var discoveryConfig = await serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IApplicationConfigService<Scan>>()!.Get();

                if (discoveryConfig.IsPeriodicDiscoveryEnabled)
                {
                    var job = JobBuilder.Create<DiscoveryJob>()
                        .WithIdentity(jobKey)
                        .Build();

                    var cronExpression = discoveryConfig.DiscoverySchedule switch
                    {
                        SimpleFrequency.Daily => "0 20 3 1/1 * ? *",
                        SimpleFrequency.Hourly => "0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *",
                        SimpleFrequency.Monthly => "0 20 3 1 1/1 ? *",
                        SimpleFrequency.Weekly => "0 20 3 ? * MON *",
                        _ => "0 20 3 1/1 * ? *"
                    };

                    var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .WithIdentity($"{discoveryConfig.DiscoverySchedule.ToString()}-trigger", "asset-discovery")
                        .StartNow()
                        //.WithCronSchedule(cronExpression, builder => builder.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed())
                        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(60)
                    .RepeatForever()
                    .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
                        .Build();

                    await _schedulerService.Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger, cancellationToken);

                    _logger.LogInformation($"ScheduleInternal() -> Scheduler initialized. Trigger: {trigger.Key.Name}");
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"ScheduleInternal() -> Periodic discovery is not enabled. Turning off the scheduler...");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _logger.LogError(exception, "Failed to configure the schedules.");
            }

        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return _schedulerService.Scheduler.DeleteJob(jobKey, cancellationToken);
        }

        public class DiscoveryJob : IJob
        {
            private readonly ILogger<DiscoveryJob> logger;
            private readonly IAssetDiscoveryManager discoveryManager;
            private readonly ILicensingService licensingService;
            private readonly INotificationSender notificationSender;
            private string start;
            private string end;

            public DiscoveryJob(ILogger<DiscoveryJob> logger, IAssetDiscoveryManager discoveryManager, ILicensingService licensingService, INotificationSender notificationSender)
            {
                this.logger = logger;
                this.discoveryManager = discoveryManager;
                this.licensingService = licensingService;
                this.notificationSender = notificationSender;
            }

            public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"Execute() -> Periodic Asset Discovery Triggered.: [{DateTime.Now:o}]");

                if (!licensingService.IsLicenseValid())
                {
                    await notificationSender.SendAsync(Codes.Data_Asset_PeriodicScanNotStarted_LicenseIssue, "Periodic asset discovery not started due to license issue.", NotificationLevel.Critical);
                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    var scan = new Scan
                    
                    {

                        IPRange = new List<IPRange>
                         {
                           new IPRange { StartIP = "10.0.0.10,EndIP = "10.0.0.18" },
                           new IPRange { StartIP = "10.0.0.1", EndIP = "10.0.0.5" },
                          }

                    };




                    var ipList = new List<DiscoveryRequest>();

                    foreach (var ipRange in scan.IPRange)
                    {
                        var discoveryRequest = new DiscoveryRequest
                        {
                            StartIpAddress = ipRange.StartIP,
                            EndIpAddress = ipRange.EndIP
                        };

                        ipList.Add(discoveryRequest);
                    }

                    foreach (var ip in ipList)
                    {
                        var discoveryTask = Task.Run(() => discoveryManager.Discover(ip));
                        await discoveryTask; // Wait for the scanning to complete

                        var discoveryStatus = discoveryTask.Result;
                        // Process the discovery status as needed

                        // Delay before scanning the next IP address
                        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                    }

                    await notificationSender.SendAsync(Codes.Data_Asset_PeriodicScanStarted, "Periodic asset discovery started.");
                }
                catch (ArgException argException)
                {
                    if (argException.MessageCode != Codes.Scan_Asset_NotFound) // Scan_Asset_NotFound is expected when there are no assets, so no need to log.
                    {
                        await notificationSender.SendAsync(Codes.Data_Asset_PeriodicScanFailed, "Failed to start periodic discovery.", NotificationLevel.Error);
                        logger.LogError(Codes.Data_Asset_PeriodicScanFailed, argException, "Failed to start periodic discovery.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    await notificationSender.SendAsync(Codes.Data_Asset_PeriodicScanFailed, "Failed to start periodic discovery.", NotificationLevel.Error);
                    logger.LogError(Codes.Data_Asset_PeriodicScanFailed, exception, "Failed to start periodic discovery.");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This file is the periodic asset discovery.cs.This file contains the automated discovery of assets in a periodic interval.

```
    public record Scan
    {
      

        /// <summary>Flag indicates whether periodic scan is enabled or not.</summary>
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Validation_Value_Required")]
        public bool IsPeriodicDiscoveryEnabled { get; init; }

        /// <summary>The frequency when the scan has to be performed.</summary>
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Validation_Value_Required")]
        public SimpleFrequency DiscoverySchedule { get; init; }

        public List<IPRange> IPRange { get; set; }
       
    }
    public class IPRange{
        public string StartIP { get; set; }
        public string EndIP { get; set; }
    }
    
}
```

This is the property class.

```
   /// <summary>
        /// Gets the scan configuration.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The scan configuration.</returns>
        [HttpGet("Scan")]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        [ProducesResponseType(statusCode: StatusCodes.Status200OK, type: typeof(Scan))]
        [ProducesResponseType(statusCode: StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        [ProducesResponseType(statusCode: StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, type: typeof(SyskeyProblemDetails))]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Scan>> GetScanConfig()
        {
            logger.LogDebug($"GetScanConfig() -> Scan configuration viewed. ");

            return await applicationConfigFactory.GetConfigService<Scan>().Get();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the Scan configuration
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The Scan configuration</returns>
        [HttpPut("Scan")]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        [ProducesResponseType(statusCode: StatusCodes.Status200OK, type: typeof(Scan))]
        [ProducesResponseType(statusCode: StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, type: typeof(SyskeyProblemDetails))]
        [ProducesResponseType(statusCode: StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, type: typeof(SyskeyProblemDetails))]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateScanConfig(
            [FromBody] Scan scanConfig)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"UpdateScanConfig() -> Scan configuration updated. ");

            var resultToReturn = await applicationConfigFactory.GetConfigService<Scan>().Update(scanConfig);

            auditLogger.LogInformation(Codes.Config_Scan_Updated, "Scan configuration updated. {@newConfig}", scanConfig);
            
            return Ok(resultToReturn);
        }
```

The api call for this.

In assert periodic discover class instead of hardcode values of ip I need a dynamic value which is stored in database when user gives ip(start and end) as a input. I need to need that userinuput and i want it to pass here. I don't know how to do it. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

here IP ranges are a list so user can give two are more items as IPRange accoring to that I want to capture and pass it here and I want to perform periodic discovery.